# Angular RxJS Observable: takeUntil vs. unsubscribe with a Subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, unsubscribe

There are several ways to unsubscribe from observables on Angular components (by using ngOnDestroy). Which option below should be preferred and why (e.g. technical reasons, performance, etc.)?

### Option 1: takeUntil

Using RxJS takeUntil to unsubscribe

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject();

  public flights: FlightModel[];

  constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flightService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

### Option 2: .unsubscribe()

Explict call .unsubscribe(), e.g. by using a separate subscription instance

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private readonly subscriptions = new Subscription();

  public flights: FlightModel[];

  constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const subscription = this.flightService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));

    this.subscriptions.add(subscription);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

### Option 3: takeWhile

Using RxJS takeWhile unsubscribe

### Option n: ?

Comment: You could ask ten people and they all could have their own preference. All the options you mentioned are perfectly valid and there's no clear 'best'. IMO takeUntil is the best solution.

Comment: ok, I was wondering if there are technical reasons for one or another options... Thanks for your comment

Comment: @HoraceP.Greeley I know it's late but why the need for  this.destroy$.next(); on Option 1?

Comment: @raberana next() is required due to "takeUntil" passes until destroy$ has a value by calling destory$.next(). Another topic, but important: takeUntil should be at the last position in the pipe. See https://cartant.medium.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Comment: Angular 16 introduced [`takeUntilDestroyed()`](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed) operator function as Developer Preview. See also [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38008334/1951524) for examples or potential news.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Option 1: clean & explicit. Works like a charm
- Option 2: more procedural, less stream-like. Works like a charm. Note that your stream will not get a 'complete' event which can cause unexpected behaviour
- Option 3: takeWhile - will have the subscription stay around untill an emission is created and then the takeWhile is evaluated. This can lead to unexpected behaviour. Still, in the end works

TLDR; there is no wrong here. Choose what you see fits your needs and communicates your intent.

Ben Lesh has also written quite a good post about the different ways to unsubscribe https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

His opinion:

> You should probably be using operators like `takeUntil` to manage your RxJS subscriptions. As a rule of thumb, if you see two or more subscriptions being managed in a single component, you should wonder if you could be composing those better.

Comment: Should we use `this.destroy$.next()` and `this.destroy$.complete()` in `ngOnDestroy()` when using `takeUntil`?

Comment: `takeUntil` needs an emission so you have to `next()` something (even `undefined)`. `complete()` is redundant given that nobody is listening to that event.

Comment: Does it mean that we do not need this.destroy$.next() and this.destroy$.complete() in ngOnDestroy() when using takeUntil?

Answer (score 15):

Personally, I choose option 1 as well, which is to use `takeUntil`.

However, it is important for you to place the `takeUntil()` operator on the last RxJS operator on the pipe sequence, as explained [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef).

For instance, if we do not place `takeUntil()` as the last operator, the subscriber will remain subscribed to the subsequent `switchMap()` operator:

```
this.flightService.getAll()
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    switchMap(() => this.doSomethingElse()),
  ).subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));
```

Therefore, the right way of doing so would be this:

```
this.flightService.getAll()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.doSomethingElse()),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  ).subscribe(flights => (this.flights = flights));
```

Brian Love has written a really good [article](https://brianflove.com/2016-12-11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) on the different ways (including `unsubscribe()`, and the `takeUntil()` operator) of unsubscribing to observables. I would recommend you to take a look at it as well.

Comment: Should we use `this.destroy$.next()` and `this.destroy$.complete()` in `ngOnDestroy()` when using `takeUntil`?

Comment: @Fredrick yes we should! Apologies, my answer did not reflect that.

Comment: Then I think using `unsubscribe` seems to be better instead of `takeUntil`. Because it is shown as a showter version, but almost similar that we also call a method `onDestroy`. Is not it?

Comment: @Fredrick yes, but if you have multiple subscriptions in your component, it will be cleaner to use the `takeUntil` approach. I believe this article gives a full explanation https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: Thanks, but I also read [this](https://www.intertech.com/angular-best-practice-unsubscribing-rxjs-observables/) article and see that there is almost no difference between two approaches regarding to code lengths (one of them is inner, the other is outer block).

Comment: takeUntil is more flexible. the position of takeUntil in operators is important. but most of time we need that takeUntil is the last operator and in this time is equal to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2):

For your example I wouldn't choose any of the 3 options. When you only want to assign a value, then store the Observable and subscribe to it with async pipe.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-flights",
  templateUrl: "./flights.component.html"
})
export class FlightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {  
  public flights$: Observable<FlightModel[]>;

  constructor(private readonly flightService: FlightService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flights$ = this.flightService.getAll();
  }
}

<ng-container *ngIf="flights$ | async as flights">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let flight of flights">
    {{ flight | json }}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: His examples are contrived to provide context for the question, while your answer is the right thing to do in a real situation, it doesn't really help with the specific question.