# The RxJS objects are still can be seen in Memory?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, google-chrome-devtools

I've just learned about memory leak of the RxJS Object. So I created a small code to test if it ok when I unsubscribe the Subject. Here is my code:

```
let subj = new rxjs.Subject();
const sub1 = subj.subscribe(text => console.log(text));
subj.next('subject 1');
subj.unsubscribe();
subj = new rxjs.Subject();
const sub2 = subj.subscribe(text => console.log(text));
subj.next('subject 2');
subj.unsubscribe();
```

In Chrome's devtool, I find out that the Rx objects can be seen in the Heap snapshot. Please explain to me why, and is it ok in term of memory leak?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should also assign `subj`, `sub1` and `sub2` to `null`.

Comment: @martin I updated the code. So your suggestion is correct. So Is it mean we should always assign RxJS objects to null after call unsubscribe on it? Most of the RxJS pages I read so far never mention it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's ok. If you can still see it there it's because you've declared it as a global variable but if you do that inside a function once the function as been called it should be garbage collected. The only important thing is to unsubscribe

Comment: @maxime1992 Great. I'll happy to accept your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular RxJS Observable: takeUntil vs. unsubscribe with a Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428791/angular-rxjs-observable-takeuntil-vs-unsubscribe-with-a-subscription)

Comment: @wentjun Nope. As you see in my code, I unsubscribe all the subject but they are still in the Heap memory

Comment: AFAICT, you are calling of `unsubscribe` on the subjects and that is almost never what you want: https://ncjamieson.com/closed-subjects/

Comment: @cartant This post means there are different behavior when I call unsubscribe on the subjects and the subscribers. So I tried to call unsubscribe on the subscribers after the call to unsubscribe the subjects. Then I still see the subjects and the subscribes in the memory

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can unsubcribe using the `takeWhile()` RxJS operator, and according to the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html), it

> Emit values until provided expression is false.

You may use it through the use of pipeable operators,

```
subj
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
  ).subscribe(text => console.log(text));
```

The above subscription will be unsubscribed when `unsubscribe$` subject is 'completed'.

```
this.unsubscribe$.next();
this.unsubscribe$.complete();
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. I tried this solution, the subj still in the heap memory and now I got unsubscribe$ object in memory.

Comment: When did you call `.next` and `.complete`?